# Need help changing Structure of Array to Array of Structures

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I have the below working code. However I misread the instruction and made a structure containing arrays as opposed to an array of structures.

Below is working code from Structure of Arrays. Below that is what I think I understand about changing this to an Array of Structures, which is probably wrong. I also need to figure out how to sort the entered student IDs when printing at the end, but that is not as important. Thank you for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    int studID;
    int marks[100];
    };

int main() {

    struct student s[100];
    int i, j, val, flag=0;

    printf(" \n Please enter the students ID# followed by their grades. When done entering\n");
    printf(" grades, enter 101 to start a new student or 102 to exit entry.\n\n\n ");

    for(i=0;i<10;) {

        printf("Enter student ID#: ");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].studID);

        printf("\nFor student ID# %d\n",s[i].studID);

        for(j=0;j<100;j++) {
            printf("Enter grades: ");
            scanf("%d",&val);

            if(val>=0 && val<=100) {
                s[i].marks[j]=val;
                }
            else if(val==101) {
                s[i].marks[j]=-1;
                break;
                }
            else if(val==102) {
                s[i].marks[j]=-1;
                flag=1;
                break;
                }
            else {
                printf("\ninvalid entry\n");
                j--;
                }
            }

        printf("\n\n----------\n\n");

        i++;

        if(flag==1)
            break;
        }

    int num=i;

    for(i=0; i<num ; i++) {
        printf("\nInformation for student ID number %d:\n",s[i].studID);
        for(j=0; s[i].marks[j]!=-1; j++)
        printf("Grades: %d\n",s[i].marks[j]);
        }

    return 0;
 }
```

what I think I need to do is

```
struct student {
    int studID;
    int marks;  //remove the array from marks
    };

int main() {

    struct student s[100];
    struct student m[100];  //maybe add this second array?
```

I am not really sure where to go after that. If I remove the array from marks in the struct, anywhere `s[i].marks[j]` I get the error "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". Any help on how to get this straightened out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you did exactly what you needed to begin with. You will have multiple students each with multiple grades. That means you will have any array of structs containing an array of marks -- just like you have. Your only glaring omission is a count of grades for each student (e.g. add `unsigned nmarks;` inside `struct student` so you know how many grades each student has. You only decision is whether you use automatic storage (which limits you to your initial allocation) or dynamically allocate with `malloc` (or better `calloc`) and `realloc` as required. I'd simple add `nmarks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> misread the instruction and made a structure containing arrays as opposed to an array of structure

The simple answer is

> ***No, an Array of Structures can be made from a structure  having an array as its member or a Structure of Array***

Here in your code for the following structure :

```
struct student  //this is a structure of array
{
    int studID;
    int marks[100];
};
```

> `struct student s[100]` is definitely an **Array of structures**. So you are doing nothing against the instructions and your first code indeed is an implementation of Array of structures :)

*But, if you are not allowed to use an array as a structure member then read the rest of the answer.*

---

**Implementing without using Structure of Array :**

**Problem :** *(with your approach)*

```
struct student
{
   int studID;
   int marks; //you made array to a single variable
};
```

- Well you've removed the array inside structure but,  as you've mentioned : now you can't access the `s[i].marks[j]` ***because now*** `marks` ***is a variable that holds a single integer*** and it can't be used to store multiple values by using index like `s[i].marks[index]`

**Solution :**

- **If your goal is just to avoid using array as a structure member**, and if you want to access `marks` and store it using a subscript, then you can declare `marks` as a pointer to the base address of a dynamically allocated memory using `malloc()` function *(include* `stdlib.h` *file)* like this :

  ```
  struct student
  {
     int studID;
     int *marks;
  };
  //so now in this structure there is no array, 
  //you just have a integer and integer pointer as members
  ```
- and then, in the first `for` loop, add this :

  ```
  for(i=0;i<10;) 
  {

      printf("Enter student ID#: ");
      scanf("%d",&s[i].studID);

      s[i].marks = malloc(100*sizeof(int)); //here you are allocating memory
  ```
- you are assigning memory for `100` grades to be entered. Now if the user just enters `10` grades for the student then the rest of the allocated memory for `90` more grades is wasted. You can avoid this by reallocating the size of `s[i].marks` to just sufficient number of grades this way

  - when user enters `101`, it marks end of grades/marks for the present `student`, so you can reallocate this way :

    ```
    else if(val==101)
    {
        s[i].marks[j]=-1;
        s[i].marks = realloc(s[i].marks,(j+1)*sizeof(int)); //resize
        break;
    }  
    //`(j+1)*sizeof(int)` because there are `j` number of grades
    //and an additional `-1` to mark the end of array.
    ```
  - similarly when you enter `102`, you can resize your `s[i].marks` this way :

    ```
     else if(val==102)
    {
        s[i].marks[j]=-1;
        s[i].marks = realloc(s[i].marks,(j+1)*sizeof(int)); //resize
        flag=1;
        break;
     }
    ```
- and now you can access the elements using `s[i].marks[j]`
- and finally don't forget to free the assigned memory using `free()` funtion this way :

  ```
  for(i=0; i<num ; i++)
  {
      free(s[i].marks);
  }
  ```

---

- altogether your **code** would be :

*(without using **Structure of Arrays** )*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //don't forget to include this

struct student
{
    int studID;
    int *marks;
};

int main(void) 
{

    struct student s[100];
    int i, j, val, flag=0;

    printf(" \n Please enter the students ID# followed by their grades. When done entering\n");
    printf(" grades, enter 101 to start a new student or 102 to exit entry.\n\n\n ");

    for(i=0;i<10;) 
    {

        printf("Enter student ID#: ");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].studID);

        s[i].marks = malloc(100*sizeof(int)); //allocating memory

        printf("\nFor student ID# %d\n",s[i].studID);

        for(j=0;j<100;j++) 
        {
            printf("Enter grades: ");
            scanf("%d",&val);

            if(val>=0 && val<=100) 
            {
                s[i].marks[j]=val;
            }
            else if(val==101) 
            {
                s[i].marks[j]=-1;
                s[i].marks = realloc(s[i].marks,(j+1)*sizeof(int)); //resize
                break;
            }
            else if(val==102) 
            {
                s[i].marks[j]=-1;
                s[i].marks = realloc(s[i].marks,(j+1)*sizeof(int)); //resize
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("\ninvalid entry\n");
                j--;
            }
        }

        printf("\n\n----------\n\n");

        i++;

        if(flag==1)
            break;
    }

    int num=i;

    for(i=0; i<num ; i++) 
    {
        printf("\nInformation for student ID number %d:\n",s[i].studID);
        for(j=0; s[i].marks[j]!=-1; j++)
        printf("Grades: %d\n",s[i].marks[j]);
    }


    //freeing memory    
    for(i=0; i<num ; i++)
    {
        free(s[i].marks);
    }

 }
```

Comment: @PhilipHudson are you not allowed to use `stdlin.h` file?

Comment: If you are dynamically allocating `marks`, why not allocate `s`, and then check the index on each and `realloc` as required?

Comment: Do you mean that, instead of allocating `100*sizeof(int)` for every `s[i].marks‘, should I just allocate memory sufficient for the number grades entered by user for each s[i] @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Yes, The general approach is to allocate sufficient memory for the anticipated number of students (say 32 per class) and then the anticipated number of grades (say 12 per course). Then if you reach 32 students, you `realloc` the number of `stuct student` by some amount (say 16 or so) and if you reach the limit for marks in a given student, you `realloc` the marks by whatever makes sense (3 more for extra credit, etc.)  You can only `realloc` if you have first dynamically allocated with `malloc` (or `calloc`), etc..

Comment: yeah.. I edited using `realloc()` @DavidC.Rankin ... but first i allocate `100*sizeof(int)` and when user enters `101` or `102`, I resize the array according to the number of grades entered

Comment: That's the way I would go. General rule to to allocate some reasonably expected number (to avoid continual calls to `realloc`, not knowing more about the OP's data, `100` is fine). `realloc` as required either adding some constant number of `int`'s (say another `100`) or some multiple of the current total memory (e.g. `2x`). That approach will work for both `s` and `marks` in the OP's code. I've gotten away from just doubling `2x` of the current mem pool in favor of addition of some fixed amount (e.g. another `100` here) to prevent mem use growing too fast.

Answer (score 1):

> `//maybe add this second array?`

I don't think so. You said you want an array of structures. That's what `s` is. The fact that the structures *also* contain an array doesn't seem like a problem to me, unless it's explicitly forbidden by some weird rule.

> I am not really sure where to go after that. If I remove the array
>   from marks in the struct, anywhere `s[i].marks[j]` I get the error
>   "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".

Of course you do. If you remove the array dimension, then `marks` is an `int`, not an array. Only `s` is an array. Only arrays or pointers can be `[indexed]`.

But look at your original examples. You have 10 students, each of whom has 100 marks. By leaving the array in your `struct` definition, the code should just work. You say 'fetch student `i` and then their mark `j`'. This should work fine. Does it not? What error do you get?

Comment: No where in the instructions does it say you cant, however the feedback I received from the working code indicates he had a problem with it.

Comment: And what problem was that? Does your instructor really require you to make a 2nd array containing the marks, detached from the corresponding students? How will you re-associate students with their marks later? Anyway, SO isn't a code-writing service, so we need a defined problem to work with. Judging by all the "I think" and "I am not really sure", I don't think there is one right now. Request more information from your instructor, and guidance if possible. Asking us to guess what they want is liable to make things worse: we'll either get it wrong, or get it right but you may not understand it

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, your array of structs containing an array was correct to begin with. As noted, the only piece of the puzzle missing was adding a member to capture/store the number of marks (grades) for each *studentID*. Adding that will allow the logic to work and simplify handling program output. In fact, it will reduce to logic to something similar to the following (including sorting the results by ID):

```
...
/* constants for max students and marks */
enum { NSTD = 64, NMARK = 100 };

typedef struct {
    int sid;            /* student ID    */
    int nmarks;         /* number grades */
    int marks[NMARK];   /* grades array  */
} student;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i, j, sidx = 0;
    student s[NSTD] = {{ .sid = 0 }};
    ...
    for (; sidx < NSTD;) {  /* for each id up to max NSTD */
        int grade = 0;

        printf (" enter student ID: ");     /* enter/validate ID */
        while (scanf (" %d", &s[sidx].sid) != 1) { ... }

        printf ("  Enter grades for student %d: ", s[sidx].sid);
        while (scanf (" %d", &grade) == 1) {    /* for each grade */
            ...
            s[sidx].marks[s[sidx].nmarks++] = grade;
        }
        sidx++;     /* increment student index */
    }
    ...
```

With all of your data input and knowing how many grades each studentID has, iterating over the data becomes a simple nested loop over each studentID and mark, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < sidx; i++) {
    printf ("\n Student ID : %3d     grades :", s[i].sid);
    for (j = 0; j < s[i].nmarks; j++)
        printf ("  %2d", s[i].marks[j]);
}
```

To sort your data (or when you think *sort* anything in C) use `qsort`. The only challenge with `qsort` is writing a small function to tell `qsort` how to sort whatever you are passing. (you will be passing a pointer to `student`, so all that is required is to sort based on `student->sid`). Since the input to your comparison function will be a `const void *` (a constant void pointer), all you need do is cast to `student *` and reference the ID member:

```
int cmpsid (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    student *s1 = (student *)a;  /* technically you should add 'const' */
    student *s2 = (student *)b;  /* omitted for simmplicity */

    /* comparing (a > b) - (a < b) prevents potential overflow */
    return (s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid < s2->sid);
}
```

You can avoid the intermediate variables `s1` and `s2` by simply applying the cast within the comparison:

```
int cmpsid (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) prevents potential overflow */
    return (((student *)a)->sid > ((student *)b)->sid) - 
            (((student *)a)->sid < ((student *)b)->sid);
}
```

(whichever is clearer to you)

Your call to `qsort` to sort the array of struct `s` is simply:

```
qsort (s, sidx, sizeof *s, cmpsid); /* sort by student ID */
```

Putting it altogether and adding additional validations that make sense, you could do something like the following. The code with read the data from a text file (or prompt for input by default if no filename is given):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for qsort */

/* constants for max students and marks */
enum { NSTD = 64, NMARK = 100 };

typedef struct {
    int sid;            /* student ID    */
    int nmarks;         /* number grades */
    int marks[NMARK];   /* grades array  */
} student;

int cmpsid (const void *a, const void *b);  /* qsort comparison */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i, j, sidx = 0;
    student s[NSTD] = {{ .sid = 0 }};
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n enter student ID followed by grade (0-100)\n"
            " 101 for next student, 102 when finished.\n\n");

    for (; sidx < NSTD;) {  /* for each id up to max NSTD */

        int grade = 0, tries = 0;

        printf (" enter student ID: ");     /* enter/validate ID */
        while (scanf (" %d", &s[sidx].sid) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, " error: invalid student ID.\n");
            if (++tries == 3) {
                fprintf (stderr, " (max attempts reached, exiting.)\n");
                goto done;
            }
            printf (" enter student ID: ");
        }

        printf ("  Enter grades for student %d: ", s[sidx].sid);
        while (scanf (" %d", &grade) == 1) {    /* for each grade */
            if (grade < 0 || 102 < grade) {     /* invalid entry */
                fprintf (stderr, " warning: invalid entry '%d'.\n", grade);
                continue;
            }
            if (grade == 101) break;            /* next student */
            if (grade == 102) {                 /* exit input   */
                if (s[sidx].nmarks) sidx++;
                goto done;
            }

            s[sidx].marks[s[sidx].nmarks++] = grade;
            if (s[sidx].nmarks == NMARK) {
                fprintf (stderr, "  warning: max grades for ID %d.\n",
                        s[sidx].sid);
                break;
            }
        }
        sidx++;     /* increment student index */
    }
    done:;

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    qsort (s, sidx, sizeof *s, cmpsid); /* sort by student ID */

    for (i = 0; i < sidx; i++) {        /* output sorted data */
        printf ("\n Student ID : %3d     grades :", s[i].sid);
        for (j = 0; j < s[i].nmarks; j++)
            printf ("  %2d", s[i].marks[j]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

/* integer comparison (use for all numeric types) */
int cmpsid (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) prevents potential overflow */
    return (((student *)a)->sid > ((student *)b)->sid) - 
            (((student *)a)->sid < ((student *)b)->sid);
}

int cmpsid2 (const void *a, const void *b);
int cmpsid2 (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    student *s1 = (student *)a;  /* technically you should add 'const' */
    student *s2 = (student *)b;  /* omitted for simmplicity */

    /* comparing (a > b) - (a < b) prevents potential overflow */
    return (s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid < s2->sid);
}
```

**Example Input**

Entering 10 students with 10 grades each:

```
$ cat dat/idmarks.txt
667 82 79 78 78 97 84 85 77 95 86 101
166 97 97 88 97 74 81 98 82 93 76 101
497 77 95 80 98 71 80 91 77 75 98 101
 31 82 78 79 95 92 86 87 95 91 83 101
515 76 76 93 87 71 72 77 92 72 93 101
145 81 79 95 91 99 93 95 99 83 77 101
517 92 98 96 75 83 89 95 93 75 95 101
836 97 84 98 98 91 98 88 71 90 75 101
381 82 98 76 81 90 72 93 93 76 86 101
 11 92 86 96 88 78 91 92 76 87 82 102
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/studentmarks <dat/idmarks.txt

 enter student ID followed by grade (0-100)
 101 for next student, 102 when finished.

 <snip prompts>

 Student ID :  11     grades :  92  86  96  88  78  91  92  76  87  82
 Student ID :  31     grades :  82  78  79  95  92  86  87  95  91  83
 Student ID : 145     grades :  81  79  95  91  99  93  95  99  83  77
 Student ID : 166     grades :  97  97  88  97  74  81  98  82  93  76
 Student ID : 381     grades :  82  98  76  81  90  72  93  93  76  86
 Student ID : 497     grades :  77  95  80  98  71  80  91  77  75  98
 Student ID : 515     grades :  76  76  93  87  71  72  77  92  72  93
 Student ID : 517     grades :  92  98  96  75  83  89  95  93  75  95
 Student ID : 667     grades :  82  79  78  78  97  84  85  77  95  86
 Student ID : 836     grades :  97  84  98  98  91  98  88  71  90  75
```

Look over the code, and the other answers as well and let me know if you have any questions. Choose your struct contents so it works for you, it should make life easier.