# Refactor qsort to make it work with array of struct

Tags: c

```
#define BUFC 1024 
enum {NSTD = 64, NMARK = 100};

typedef struct student{
    int sid;
    int nmarks; /* number grades */
    int marks[NMARK]; /* grades array */
} student;

int cmpid(const void *a, const void *b );
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buf[BUFC];
    int i,j, sidx = 0;
    student s[NSTD] = {{.sid = 0,.marks = 0 }};
    
    FILE *fp =  argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1],"r") : stdin;
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr,"error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nEnter student ID followed by grad (0,100)"
            " 101 for next student, 102 when finished.\n");
    for(; sidx < NSTD;){
        int grade = 0, tries = 0;
        int n;
        int offset;
        // printf(" enter student ID, grade for student");
        
        if(!fgets(buf,BUFC,stdin)){
            fputs("\n(user canceled input)\n",stdout);
            break;
        }
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;
        char *data = buf;

        while (sscanf(data," %d%n",&n,&offset) == 1)
        {
            s[sidx].marks[s[sidx].nmarks++] = n;
            data = data + offset;
        }
        sidx ++;     
    }
    if(fp != stdin) fclose(fp);
    
    for(i = 0; i < sidx; i++){
        s[i].sid = s[i].marks[0];    
    }
    printf("sidx=%d\n",sidx);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("\nStudent ID:%3d\tgrades:",s[i].sid);
        // printf("nmarks=%d\n",s[i].nmarks);
        // for(j = 0; j<s[i].nmarks-1; j++)
        // printf("\t%2d",s[i].marks[j+1]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Before Qsort: s[0].sid=%d\n",s[0].sid);
    qsort(s,sidx, sizeof *s,cmpid);
    printf("After Qsort s[0].sid=%d\n",s[0].sid);
    return 0;
}

int cmpid(const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const struct student* s1 = (student *) a; 
    const struct student* s2 =  (student *) b; 
    return (s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid > s2->sid);
}
```

Run/Build it via `gcc array_struct20.c && ./a.out <dat/idmarks.txt` stdout as

```
Enter student ID followed by grad (0,100) 101 for next student, 102 when finished.

(user canceled input)
sidx=10

Student ID:667  grades:
Student ID:166  grades:
Before Qsort: s[0].sid=667
After Qsort s[0].sid=667
```

Context: [Need help changing Structure of Array to Array of Structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171003/need-help-changing-structure-of-array-to-array-of-structures/38179360#38179360)

Before and after qsort `s[0].sid` would be different. So how to make qsort working.

Comment: `(s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid > s2->sid)` will always be zero. Try `(s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid < s2->sid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid > s2->sid)`

`s1->sid > s2->sid` will be `0` or `1` so you'll have either `0 - 0` or `1 - 1`. The result is always `0` (meaning that they will all compare equal).

If you want them sorted in ascending order:

```c
int cmpid(const void* a, const void* b) {
    const struct student* s1 = a;
    const struct student* s2 = b;
    if(s1->sid < s2->sid) return -1;
    if(s1->sid > s2->sid) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Possible x86-64 assembly:

```
gcc                                clang

mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]       mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax       xor     ecx, ecx
mov     edx, -1                    cmp     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
setg    al                         setg    cl
movzx   eax, al                    mov     eax, -1
cmovl   eax, edx                   cmovge  eax, ecx
ret                                ret
```

You could also use the clever construct:

```
return (s1->sid > s2->sid) - (s1->sid < s2->sid);
```

In that case you may get this assembly:

```
gcc                                clang

mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]       mov     ecx, dword ptr [rdi]
cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax       xor     eax, eax
setg    al                         xor     edx, edx
setl    dl                         cmp     ecx, dword ptr [rsi]
movzx   edx, dl                    setg    al
movzx   eax, al                    setl    dl
sub     eax, edx                   sub     eax, edx
ret                                ret
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cMYGvGnGe)